# How can I Optimize this query on tables having bulk data?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I rewrite this query so as to execute it more faster?

```
DECLARE @CityID BIGINT = 89263

-- [ Execution  takes 10 sec]
SELECT distinct MHD.[CaxHotelId],[Name],[SupportedAPIS],[Longitude],[Latitude],[CityName],[CountryName]
                ,[CountryCode],[Star],[HotelChain],[Address],[Telephone],[Fax],[Email],[Website],MHD.[Description],[DisplayName]      
INTO #tbl
FROM [MasterHotelData] as MHD     
WHERE FK_MasterHotelCityId = @CityID  ;

-- OutPut Table 1  [ Execution  takes 3 sec, outputs 300 rows ]
SELECT CaxHotelId,Name,SupportedAPIS,Longitude,Latitude,CityName,CountryName,CountryCode,Star
    ,HotelChain,Address,Telephone,Fax,Email,Website,Description,DisplayName
FROM #tbl; 

-- OutPut Table 2 [ Execution  takes 30 sec, outputs 3000 rows ]
SELECT [Id]    
    ,MHI.[CaxHotelId]    
    ,CAST ([Url] AS VARCHAR(1000))   -- Original Size VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,CAST ([ThumbUrl] AS VARCHAR(1000))   -- Original Size VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,MHI.[UpdatedDate]    
FROM [MasterHotelImage] as MHI
INNER JOIN #tbl ON #tbl.CaxHotelId = MHI.CaxHotelId;

-- OutPut Table 3 [ Execution  takes 5 sec, outputs 5000 rows ]
SELECT [Id]    
    ,MHA.[CaxHotelId]    
    ,[AmenityName]    
    ,MHA.[Description]    
    ,MHA.[UpdatedDate]    
FROM [MasterHotelAmenity]  as MHA
INNER JOIN #tbl ON #tbl.CaxHotelId = MHA.CaxHotelId

DROP  TABLE #tbl
```

I have added non Clustered Index to `CaxHotelId` of `MasterHotelAmenity` and `MasterHotelImage`. Total execution of this query takes nearly 50 secs, and my employer want me to get it executed in just 10 seconds.

Comment: Create non-clustered index on FK_MasterHotelCityId also put an alias name in front of ID in the Select statement so that the SQL know where to get the column from.

Comment: Thanks. But I couldnt create an index on the above said column, `Could not allocate a new page for database 'teststatic1' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'PRIMARY'. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.`. I think I am out of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the distinct in your first query? It feels like you don't, so I'd drop it. If you did need it, try using a group by instead. In my experience they are generally much faster, although that may depend on data.

I would also define the temp table first, put an index on the CaxHotelId column and then insert into it. That may help speed up your joins

Comment: Thankyou. I created temp table and added clustered Index to its primary key. I saved my 3secs, also removed distinct. Is it true that `INSERT INTO` temp table will log more than `SELECT INTO` temp table? I have read this in stackoverflow itself.

Comment: Huh, after some googleing it looks like it is. I didn't know that! You can  select into an existing table though; so, select into #tbl select <cols> from <tbl1> join <tbl2> on <tb1.cols> = <tb2.cols>... I'm not in a position to test it myself, and its not the expensive part of your query, but it may do something there